# ggiraph plot is shifted in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggiraph

This is my example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

df <- data.frame(achseX = c("A", "b"), achseY = c(12, 22))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderggiraph({
    gg <- ggplot(data = df) + geom_bar_interactive(aes(tooltip = achseY, x = achseX, y = achseY), stat = "identity") +
      theme_minimal()
    return(ggiraph(code = print(gg), selection_type = "multiple", zoom_max = 4,
                   hover_css = "fill:#FF3333;stroke:black;cursor:pointer;",
                   selected_css = "fill:#FF3333;stroke:black;"))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  "The plot should start right under this text.",
  ggiraphOutput("plot") ,
  "This is where the plot should end."
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I start the app, the result looks like:

[image]

I added the text lines to show where the plot should be positioned. As you can see, the plot is shifted to another position. The same thing happens when I start the shiny examples:

```
# example 1: 
shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("shiny/crimes", package = "ggiraph"), display.mode = "showcase")
# example 2:
shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("shiny/cars", package = "ggiraph"), display.mode = "showcase")
```

> Did I missed something? How can I get this plot to the right position?

**EDIT:**

Session info:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gdtools_0.1.4 ggiraph_0.4.0 ggplot2_2.2.1 shiny_1.0.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_1.0.0         Rcpp_0.12.11      compiler_3.4.0    plyr_1.8.4        R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.5.0    
 [7] base64enc_0.1-3   tools_3.4.0       digest_0.6.12     uuid_0.1-2        jsonlite_1.5      tibble_1.3.3     
[13] gtable_0.2.0      rlang_0.1.1       DBI_0.7           yaml_2.1.14       officer_0.1.4     dplyr_0.5.0      
[19] xml2_1.1.1        htmlwidgets_0.8   grid_3.4.0        R6_2.2.2          rvg_0.1.4         purrr_0.2.2.2    
[25] magrittr_1.5      scales_0.4.1      htmltools_0.3.6   assertthat_0.2.0  mime_0.5          xtable_1.8-2     
[31] colorspace_1.3-2  httpuv_1.3.5      labeling_0.3      lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     R.oo_1.21.0
```

Comment: Could you add `sessionInfo()` results and also tell me what browser you are using (I can't reproduce your issue on my mac)

Comment: What is `ggiraph` in your code? edit: i though it is a typo. now i see there is a package with that name :)

Comment: @DavidGohel thanks for your fast response. It seems that it is a visualisation problem of the RStudio Viewer. I had the same issue in the Internet Explorer. When I open it in Chrome, it works fine. So guess this topic is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will spend time later investing that, I thought it was ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a visualisation bug in RStudio and Internet Explorer. It works fine in Google Chrome. Could not test it for Mozilla Firefox though.

Comment: There is exactly same problem with `plotly` --> it is not properly displayed in IE, however in my case in Mozilla Firefox it works perfect.